# SQL sum records that wont appear in the final result

Tags: sql, datetime, sum, where-clause, window-functions

new to SQL and I've got an issue I’m not quite managing to sort out

Table1

```
ID   name          purchase_date   purchase_value  
---------------------------------------------------
 1   John Doe      01/01/2020             10  
 1   John Doe      30/01/2020             25  
 1   John Doe      20/02/2020             20  
 2   Santa Claus   01/01/2020             15
```

What I want to be able to do –
Select records from table1 where in a set date range (lets say more recent than 19/2/2020 for the sake of the example), but I want to show total spend for the records regardless of whether they are in the range

Eg I want to show

```
ID  name       purchase_date   purchase_value   Total_Purchase_value  
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1   John Doe   20/02/2020             20                 55
```

Ie Santa Clause doesn't appear at all as he has no purchases in the date range, and I just see one record for John Doe for his purchase that is after 19/2/2020 but the total purchase value sums all 3 of his transactions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, sum(purchase_value) over(partition by id) total_purchase_value
    from table1 t
) t
where purchase_date > date '2020-02-19'
```

Within the subquery, the window `sum()` computes the total purchase amount for each `id`. Then, the outer query filters on dates that fall within the target range.

You did not tell which database you are using, so this uses the standard syntax for date literals. You might need to ajust that to the syntax that your database supports.

Comment: Thanks so much guys, very helpful as I've got it sorted now!

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*,
from (select t.*, sum(purchase_value) over (partition by id) as total
      from t
     ) t
where date >= '2020-02-19'
```

Comment: Thanks so much guys, very helpful as I've got it sorted now!